# Strange low frequency sawtooth in a 110 kHz Hartley oscillator

Tags: bjt, oscillator, debugging, sine, sawtooth-waveform

I am trying to build a Hartley oscillator for 110 kHz using a BJT according to the following schematic: [image]
[image]

I am assuming \$ \beta=100\$ and \$ V_t=25mV \$

The collector current is about 1.63 mA, Vc is 9.62 V, and Vb is 4.71 V; with this biasing, I expected a maximum gain (when Rt is set to 0) to be about (=Rc/re and re=Vt/Ic=25mV/1.63 mA=15.63 Ω) 215.16 and an amplifier input resistance of about \$r_e\beta\||(56k||22k)= 1.5k \$ and output resistance of 3.3k at resonance, the LC netwrok will attenuate the signal by \$ \frac{1.5k}{1.5k+(3.3||1.5)k}=0.59\$, but since the gain is very large, stable oscillations should ensue. I have also added diodes to limit the voltage swing

**The output**

I see oscillations close to the desired frequency
[image]

However when I decrease the time div, I see these strange spikes which I don't understand at all[image]

The separation between these spikes changes when I change Rt, but they don't merge into a continuous wave train, which was the expected outcome. Further, the collector voltage when viewed with AC coupling looks like an RC waveform of sorts[image] Zooming in to the edge of the sawtooth shows the expected sine wave at about 100 kHz.

**My question**
What is happening here? It seems that the coupling capacitors are discharging, causing a reduction in the gain and decay of oscillations. Once the oscillations die down, they charge again, increasing the gain causing oscillations to start, and the cycle goes on. Is this logic correct? And finally, is there any way to get rid of these spikes?

Comment: No decoupling capacitor ?

Comment: Waveform looks like classic squegging oscillation. Try reducing the coupling capacitor values to give closer to give a time constant of say 1-10 cycles of the intended frequency.  Reduce loop gain closer to the minimum required to sustain oscillation.  @Antonio51: It's supplied through large-value resistors, and the frequency is low; bypass won't make much difference.

Comment: Have you tried simulating the circuit?

Comment: @Andyaka I simulated the circuit in LT Spice and saw steady oscillations

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you for the suggestion; I will try it and let you know. Also, where do you add the bypass that Antonio51 suggested in cases where it is required? I thought I had covered all the decoupling capacitors.

Comment: @amoghwaghmare please show the simulation circuit and waveforms.

Comment: Try to Desrease input coupling capacitor to nanofarads so it has enough energy just for oscillation per period( not burst).

Comment: I think the stray capacitance between the rows of contacts and the long wires all over the place on the breadboard are causing the problem. Use a compact pcb layout instead.

Answer (score 1):

I simulated with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).
Not very "sinusoidal" and "slow" at starting ...

[image]

Without the 2 diodes, it should be more "sinusoidal".

[image]

[image]